# Why is parseInt() not converting my String of numbers correctly?

Tags: javascript, string, integer, parseint

I have some logic within a function that takes a string of numbers called digits like so:

```
6145390195186705543
```

I then attempt to convert with parseInt() like so:

> parseInt(digits)

The result of:

```
digits = parseInt(digits);
```

is

> 6145390195186705000

Can someone help me understand why this is the case? and how i can get an accurate conversion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another version of ["broken" floating point math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken): Javascript uses 64 bits to store numbers as small as the size of an atom up to the number of atoms in the universe. As that is quite a broad range it cannot be stored accurately, therefore the numbers are stored in an imprecise way but can represent a very broad range. In your case `6145390195186705000` is the inaccurate version JS is able to store as `6145390195186705543` cannot be stored.

> and how i can get an accurate conversion?

You cannot store an "accurate number", therefore you cannot convert it accurately. However there are some libraries that allow you to work with strings as if they were numbers, such as [BigIntJS](https://github.com/DamonAnderson/BigIntJS).

---

As this is a common problem, this is going to be solved in the next JS version, see this [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint/blob/master/README.md). You can currently test it in the new version of chrome.

Comment: Damn, is there an easy way to go around this or do i need to concentrate on the last digits as an approach.

Comment: @newScientists yeah there are some libraries out there

Comment: I cant use a library, will post the algorithm and solution when i find it. thanks for the help